# Rails - grouped_options_for_select

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, optgroup

I am having some difficulty populating a select box in Rails with option groups using `grouped_options_for_select`.

I currently have 3 instance variables that I would like to add to one entire grouped array for the grouped select box.

For example,  I have:

```
@fruits (which contains the object(s))
   --- !ruby/object:Fruits
      attributes:
      id: 2
      name: Banana

@veggies (which contains the object(s))
   --- !ruby/object:Veggies
      attributes:
      id: 23
      name: Celery
   --- !ruby/object:Veggies
      attributes:
      id: 24
      name: Carrots

@junk_food (which contains the object(s))
   --- !ruby/object:Junk
      attributes:
      id: 11
      name: Snickers
   --- !ruby/object:Junk
      attributes:
      id: 12
      name: Ice Cream
```

My question is:  How do I take these 3 instance variables and turn them into a grouped select, like:

```
  <select>
    <optgroup label="Fruits">
      <option value="2">Banana</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Veggies">
      <option value="23">Celery</option>
      <option value="24">Carrots</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Junk">
      <option value="11">Snickers</option>
      <option value="12">Ice Cream</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

**food_controller.erb**

```
@fruits = Fruit.all
@veggies = Veggies.all
@junk_food = JunkFood.all

# Then, I'd create the array here using the items above?
```

I know I am supposed to be using `grouped_items_for_select`, but I continue running into a bunch of errors and I am not sure of the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `grouped_options_for_select` method indeed is the correct one.
Since you haven't provided code, this should result in the grouped options you want:

```
grouped_options_for_select [['Fruits',  @fruits.collect {|v| [ v.name, v.id ] }],
                            ['Veggies', @veggies.collect {|v| [ v.name, v.id ] }],
                            ['Junk',    @junk_food.collect {|v| [ v.name, v.id ] }]]
```

Which can be used to create the dropdown:

```
select_tag 'Food', grouped_options_for_select(...)
```

or with form_helper:

```
f.select :food_attribute, grouped_options_for_select(...)
```