# Assign role from drop down tab in signup in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I have followed the ruby on rails tutorial in my design of a web app and am now venturing off on my own to add in some functionality that isn't covered in the tutorial.

Currently, I am trying to allow the user to select their role upon signup. I think a drop down select would work, but I would like it to toggle either 'scout' or 'leader' to true (boolean fields in the user model). I'm not exactly sure how to do that with `<%= f.select %>` though. Possibly something like

```
<%= select(:scout, [['Scout', true], ['Leader', true]]) %>
```

but that won't work because it only assigns into the scout boolean. I hope I made my problem clear enough. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use grouped_options_for_select, check the document out http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select or check this example out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522464/rails-grouped-options-for-select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your intent, but with your current design, you can do this:

In your model, add a callback `before_save :process_user_role`

```
class User
  ...
  before_save :process_user_role
  ...
  def process_user_role
    self.leader = true unless self.scout
  end
end
```

Above code will have help you to set `leader` field to `true` when `scout` field set to false. Otherwise do nothing :)

---

While above solution should work fine, but there is an other solution that more elegant is use `ActiveRecord::Enum` to manage Role of User.

You can learn it here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Awesome! I made the select tag `<%= f.select(:scout, [['Scout', true], ['Leader', false]]) %>` and used your `process_user_role` code and nothing broke :) Thanks!

Comment: @mjswartz you're welcome, and I just update the answer with another approach :)

Comment: I think in the future I will not use independent booleans to manage roles. I'd like to eventually give the user a role field and have a joining table user_role from user to role, where role is a table containing all roles. That would seem like the best approach, but I'm not good enough to do it... YET!

Comment: @mjswartz just give it a try when you have spare time, and if you have any problem, ask for help from awesome people here :D

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
<%= select(:role, [['Scout', 'scout'], ['Leader', 'leader']]) %>
```

this will store data in `:role` And later on you can compare the type of `role`

Comment: This gives `NameError in UsersController#new: undefined local variable or method role`. I tried to define role in the users controller new method, but it still gave an error. How do I work around that?

Comment: you have to have `role` as column in database which will store the type of role as string from the input form